# Django model manager objects.create where is the documentation?

Tags: python, django

I always read that I should use

```
model = Model(a=5, b=6)
model.save()
```

But I just saw there is a manager function create, because I saw an opensource django app using it.

```
model = Model.objects.create(a=5, b=6)
print model.pk
1
```

So is it suggested to use it? Or is it still preferred to use the .save method. I'm guessing that objects.create will try to create it no matter what, whereas save may save an existing object if the pk is specified.

These are the docs that I found: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#creating-objects

Comment: why did this question get a down vote? i just arrived here with the same question and found this useful.

Comment: I also didnt know, maybe people thought it was stupid and obvious. Don't care so much about it :P i got my answer im happy. I also searched without result so I asked.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It's in the page ["QuerySet API reference"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#create), linked from the documentation index.

Answer (score 49):

```
p = Person.objects.create(first_name="Bruce", last_name="Springsteen")
```

**equivalent to:**

```
p = Person(first_name="Bruce", last_name="Springsteen") 
p.save(force_insert=True)
```

> The force_insert means that a new object will always be created.
>   Normally you won’t need to worry about this. However, if your model
>   contains a manual primary key value that you set and if that value
>   already exists in the database, a call to create() will fail with an
>   IntegrityError since primary keys must be unique. Be prepared to
>   handle the exception if you are using manual primary keys.

Answer (score 4):

create essentially does the same. below is the source code for create.

```
def create(self, **kwargs):
    """
    Creates a new object with the given kwargs, saving it to the database
    and returning the created object.
    """
    obj = self.model(**kwargs)
    self._for_write = True
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
    return obj
```

it creates an instance and then saves it.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, these two methods are [equivalent](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#create). The usage of `Model.objects.create` could be preferred since it is more suited to the style of Django.